# Как организовать отмену действия в Снэкбаре в Чистой архитектуре?

Tags: android, архитектура

После некоторого действия пользователя (например, удаление элемента) показывается `SnackBar` с кнопкой "Отмена". Если успеть её нажать, то действие надо отменить.

С одной стороны, это действие короткое и можно попробовать разрулить всё в презентере. Но тогда нужно быть внимательным с состоянием этого процесса, чтобы не продублировать команду и корректно отменить, если нужно. С другой стороны, отмена операции - бизнес логика, и нужно как-то учитывать это.

Как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Презентер сообщает действие интерактору только по событию: **SnackBar скрылся**, то есть только после того как пользователь решил не отменять действие.

Важно заранее учесть, что пользователь может сразу после действия выйти с экрана или приложения. Тогда надо принять решение - либо также передать действие интерактору при деттаче вью, лтбо считать такое поведение пользователя тоже отменой действия.